# How to upload HDF5 file directly to S3 bucket in Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, hdf5

I want to upload a HDF5 file created with h5py to S3 bucket without saving locally using boto3.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491839/any-way-to-write-files-directly-to-s3-using-boto3) uses pickle.dumps and pickle.loads and other solutions I have found, store the file locally which I like to avoid.

Comment: `pickle.dump` dumps it as a file, but you can use `pickle.dumps` to dump it as bytes. So then you can upload that bytes to S3.

Comment: Thanks, but then reading the uploaded file, one needs to use ```pickle.loads```, right? I want to upload the file as a HDF5 file so that it can be just read as a HDF5 file without the need for ```pickle.loads```.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`io.BytesIO()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) to and [`put_object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703634/how-to-import-a-text-file-on-aws-s3-into-pandas-without-writing-to-disk) as illustrated here [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485660/python-uploading-a-plot-from-memory-to-s3-using-matplotlib-and-boto). Hope this helps. Even in this case, you'd have to 'store' the data locally(though 'in memory'). You could also create a [`tempfile.TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) and then upload your file with [`put_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileKeykey). I don't think you can *stream* to an S3 Buckets in the sense that the local data would be discarded as it is uploaded to the Bucket.

Comment: What is the appropriate x for `put_object(h5bytestream, ContentType=x)`? The example linked uses `ContentType='image/png'` but I'm not sure how to find the appropriate MIME type descriptor

Comment: you don't actually need to specify `ContentType`, it's optional