# Write pandas dataframe to S3 using HDF5 format

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, hdf5

If you pass an S3 path (anything starting with `s3://`) to pandas's `to_csv` method, it will save the dataframe directly to S3. This does not work with `to_hdf`.

Do I have to use boto3 to save the file on S3, or can I do it directly with Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas documentation is asymmetrical in that respect in the sense that [`read_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html) allow to specify an S3 url, while [`to_hdf5`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf) does **not**. My personnal impression is that it is because `to_hdf5` has an `append` mode (a) and [S3 does not support append operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783903/append-data-to-an-s3-object). 
So to answer your question more specifically, yes, you wold have to use `boto3` to export your file to your bucket once it has been created. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788762/how-to-upload-hdf5-file-directly-to-s3-bucket-in-python/58544864#58544864) for some strategies.